# Play Frameworkが起動したH2DBのWebConsoleを開く方法

Tags: playframework

Play Frameworkで作成したアプリケーションをsbt runするとH2DBが起動すると思いますが、
このH2DBの状態をWebConsoleから確認するにはどうしたら良いですか？

[実行環境]
Play 2.5

build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "1.1.1",
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "1.1.1",
evolutions,
"com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.191",
cache,
ws,
specs2 % Test)
```

application.conf

```
slick.dbs.default.driver="slick.driver.H2Driver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="org.h2.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:h2:mem:test"
```

Comment: `activator`から起動するとh2-browserとplayframework自身が同一プロセスで起動するのでインメモリ組み込みモードでも問題なく接続できるはず([参考](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25470240/4506703))ですが、そうではなく、あくまでも`sbt run`で、ということでしょうか。(playframeworkについて知識がないので頓珍漢な質問ならすみません)

Comment: ありがとうございます。 参考URLの方法で組み込みモードのH2DBを閲覧することができました。
改めて質問に記載して頂ければベストアンサーにしたいと思っているのですが、よろしいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H2の接続文字列が"jdbc:h2:mem:test"ですので、インメモリの組み込みモードで動作していることになります。
このため、アプリケーションにとって外部となるWebConsoleから当該のH2dbにはアクセスできません。

WebConsoleで覗く方法としては、H2をサーバモードで動かし、アプリケーション側がそのサーバモードで動いているH2に接続する方法があります。

または、リアルタイムではなくなりますが、接続文字列をjdbc:h2:/root/testのようにしてアプリケーションを動作させると/root/test.h2.dbというファイルが出来上がるのでそちらにJDBC接続することでDBの中身を確認することができます。

Comment: H2をサーバーモードで起動するには、application.confはどう書いたら良いですか？

Comment: H2のWebConsoleを起動すると、あわせてH2がサーバーモードで起動するはずです。その場合、application.confの接続文字列は、"jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/test"と指定するとイケるとおもいます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらの方法もうまく確認できました。